# Class variable and Instance variable in Python

Tags: python, class, variables

I am practicing python classes. I got that classes variables are shared among all the instances, while instance variables belongs to each object, and thus need to be defined for each instance. In the following classes, in reference to the variable raise_amount, if I write the last code line like that: `self.pay = int(self.pay * Employee.raise_amount)`, the behavior is the same.

What is the difference between the two cases, if any?

```
class Employee:

    raise_amount = 1.04

    def __init__(self ,first ,last ,pay ):

        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first+"."+last+"@company.com"

    def apply_raise(self): #but this is not an attribute
        self.pay = int(self.pay * self.raise_amount) 
       #or self.pay = int(self.pay * Employee.raise_amount)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see two different cases in your question. The last line is already written like this.

Comment: Thierry I think they meant with and without the self on the raise amount.

Comment: I don't know, but until that is clarified, the question doesn't really mean anything...

Comment: sorry guys, there was a typo. just edited the question. The alternative last line was self.pay = int(self.pay * Employee.raise_amount), thus using the class name instead of self

Answer (score 1):

I assume your are referring to the self.raise_amount.   In the case where you have it as that python must first look for instance variable and if not found it looks for similarly named class variable and creates a copy of it as an instance variable and uses that.  if you were to then change the self.raise amount it would only be for the instance and not for any other instance made from the class.

Try creating an instance of the class and use the apply_raise method on it.   then try changing the raise_amount class variable to something like 2.0 and call the method on the instance again.  what you should see is that the amount only goes up 1.04 times, not 2.   that is because it used the instance value it created the first time you ran the method.

Note: original post was edited to change to use the Class name for the raise amount.   This post was a reply while it was self.raise_amount.

Comment: sorry there was a typo int he question. what if the last line of code is self.pay = int(self.pay * Employee.raise_amount) , thus using the class name instead of self? Thanks

Comment: So my answer is a bit off relative to your current code but I hope it helps.  Using the variable name with the self. in front of it will make a copy of the class variable and use that, but once that its done the self.  variable is an instance variable and specific to the one instance it is a member of.

Answer (score 1):

The lookup for the expression `self.raise_amount` can be complicated in general, be we can simplify it knowing that there are no methods or descriptors involved.

1. If `self` has an instance attribute named `raise_amount`, the value of that attribute is returned.
2. Otherwise, we start looking for *class* attributes, starting with the immediate type of `self`, here `Employee`. Since `Employee.raise_amount` is defined, we get that value...
3. ... but what if `Employee.raise_amount` *hadn't* been defined? We would have moved on to the next class in the method resolution order of `Employee`, namely `object`. Since `object.raise_amount` is not defined, an `AttributeError` would have been raised.